# Wrong Path of Mysql in Xampp

Tags: php, mysql, xampp

I am using Mysql for long time via xampp software and it is working fine. Now i installed Mysql software, While configuring Mysql software i give port 3307, to run it independently from Mysql in Xampp which is using 3306. But it is not working , I got following error when i run xampp I got screen with following error saying

> MySQL Service detected with wrong path
>    Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
>    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
>    Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysqld" --defaults- file="C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\my.ini" MySQL
>   Expected Path: c:\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file=c:\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Simple if you using windows Go to Administrative cmd and type the following command

```
sc delete MySQL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with windows command prompt with administrative mode

sc delete MySQL .
from above commands